# check if a key is found in a map c++ and obtains it

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to check if a certain key is found in a map, if so i want to put it in a variable for other uses, but the thing is I dont want to use iterators. I found the find function in the map class, but it returns an iterator, I want to like check if a key is found in map, if it returns true to obtain it

Thanks

Comment: the iterator gives you exactly what you need.

Comment: Iterators are what everything in the STL uses. Why would you need to get around that?

Comment: Iterator is the way to go .. Using a map without iterator is liking trying to fetch water without a bucket from Well ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::map::count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count) will inform you if the map contains a particular key. If the key is in the map, then you could use `operator[]` to get at the value, knowing that a default value will not be added (though as ildjarn points out would require two searches of the map):

```
std::map<int, int> m;

m[0] = 1;
m[1] = 2;

if (m.count(0))
{
    std::cout << "value=" << m[0] << "\n";
}
```

Why `find()` is unattractive, is not clear to me:

```
std::map<int, int>::iterator i = m.find(0);
if (i != m.end())
{
    std::cout << "value=" << i->second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: While this would work, `count()` + `operator[]` will cause a double-lookup, which is silly in terms of efficiency when there's `find()`. Demonstrating how to use `find()` may make for a better answer.

Comment: @ildjarn, I agree and was updating answer to show both approaches.